# ruby URI.escape and URI.encode and URI.parse error

Tags: ruby, uri

ruby version 2.2.2

```
url = "http://www.rugbyontario.com/AboutUs/NewsStories/LatestNews/tabid/15402/sni[20577]/4831/language/en-US/Default.aspx"
URI.parse(URI.encode(url))
```

This gives:

```
*** URI::InvalidURIError Exception: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.rugbyontario.com/AboutUs/NewsStories/LatestNews/tabid/15402/sni[20577]/4831/language/en-US/Default.aspx
```

The actual url is working in browser, and I am already trying to escape it, it still gives me an error. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have searched around, the answer to many questions are just use `URI.encode` to encode first, but in my case I still have the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `addressable` gem now, this one escapes the urls correctly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I'm not very used to reading RfCs, however, from what I could gleam from RfC3986, `[` and `]` are indeed illegal in the path component of a URI. So, Ruby is right: the URI is invalid.

The fact that your browser accepts it doesn't mean a thing. Browsers have been known to accept broken input in order to not annoy non-technical users.

Comment: `[ ]` are indeed invalid, but `URI.encode` does not escape them is the problem. `Addressable::URI.encode` escapes the `[ ]`.